# How to hide a particular anchor tag which doesnt have any id or class using jquery?

Tags: jquery, anchor

How to hide a particular anchor tag which doesn't have any id or class using jquery? Here i want to hide one of the below anchor tag
HTML

```
<ul class="menubar">
  <li><a href="pictorial-journey.html">Pictorial Journey</a></li> 
  <li><a href="resp.html">Resp</a></li>
  <li><a href="editor.html">Editor</a></li>
</ul>

var a_href = $('.menubar li a').attr("href");  
if(a_href =='pictorial-journey.html'){
  $(this).parents('li').hide();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`attribute selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) as follow.

```
$('a[href="pictorial-journey.html"]').parents('li').hide();
```

This will hide all the *ancestor* `li`, of the `anchor` whose `href` is "pictorial-journey.html".

To hide only single `li` use `closest()`.

```
$('a[href="pictorial-journey.html"]').closest('li').hide();
```

Comment: I think [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) would be the preferred method for finding the single matching parent that may or may not be one DOM level above.  I believe `parents()` could return elements from above if the list is nested